# Как получить количество массива

Tags: массивы

Как можно получить `Count []` то есть после `regex` сколько получилось массива из этого текста

```
String fileText = "C:\\Oracle\\Middleware\\user_projects\\domains\\base_domain\\test.docx";
String fileString;
File file = new File(fileText);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(fis);
XWPFParagraph[] paragraphs = document.getParagraphs();
for (XWPFParagraph para : paragraphs) {
    fileString = para.getText();
    fileString = fileString.trim();
    fileString = Arrays.toString(fileString.split("\\.", 1));
    System.out.println(fileString);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

пробовал писать `paragraphs.length` ?